# Angular.js // Getting element by attribute value

Tags: angularjs, selector, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having the following in a json response :

```
[
   "alt_sizes":[
      {"width":500,"height":333,"url":"http://..."},  
      {"width":400,"height":266,"url":"http://..."},
      {"width":250,"height":167,"url":"http://..."},
      {"width":100,"height":67,"url":"http://..."},
      {"width":75,"height":75,"url":"http://..."}
   ]
]
```

I parse my object with somehow the following

```
obj.alt_sizes[0]
```

But what if I wanted to get with angular.js the element having a specific width or height ?
Selecting the small one, having 75 for its width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter filter to do this:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.items, {width:'75'})
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mP3LLHgJSIEbe16HrO6f?p=preview